# HTML Validator giving me Element “head” is missing a required instance of child element “title”

Tags: html

there isn't much to this code, but I keep getting this error from the validator: "Element “head” is missing a required instance of child element “title”. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm1>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DS2</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

your html tag is not correct

`<html>` not `<htm1>`

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ah, that worked and I'm a fool. Thank you!